# What is the difference between transitive and intransitive finite complementizers?

Tags: syntax

I know that an intransitive verb accepts only one argument, i.e., the subject. So, such verbs do not need a complement. But how could one understand the concept of an intransitive complementizer, in Chomskyan syntax? After all, isn’t the very nature of complementizers to accept a complement?

Edit: According to [Andrew Radford](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154274X), "none of the English finite complementisers (e.g. *if*, *that*, <s>*that*</s> and the null finite complementiser ∅ found in main clauses) are transitive".  So, in what sense is the complementizer *that*, for example, intransitive? How does it differ from other complementizers that could be classified as transitive in other languages?

Comment: You should give at least one example.

Comment: I also think you have an unusual definition of transitivity: in my book, a transitive verb is one that can have a direct object, whereas an intransitive one cannot; it says nothing about other complements. Copulae, for example, are intransitive, but they have a subject complement as a complement (don't be confused by the two entirely different kinds of "complement" in that sentence).

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, I think my comparison with verbs is not helping. What I want to know is: what characterizes a transitive complementizer and an intransitive one? Suppose you were given the task of categorizing a certain complementizer, from some language, as either transitive or intransitive. What criteira would you use? To what aspects would you pay attention to?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: Okay, very good question. I have wondered about this myself. I suspect that there might not be a hard criterion that can be independently established for each language independently; but I'd say it is a phenomenon that is described as a complex across languages, in the language family as a whole.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Every search for "(in)transitive complementizer" ends in Radford or someone quoting him.  Is he the only one to use the term?  It seems he is referring solely to case assignment; he doesn't discuss how arguments come into play.  I don't yet see how *for*, his only example of a transitive complementizer, would have two arguments.

Comment: @lettuce, I couln't find the term being used anywhere else. And even in the book I cited, he doesn't get into much detail about the matter. So, I hope there is some linguist out ther that could clarify this issue for me.

Comment: Well I tried to find what I could (motivated by my own curiosity at this point) but it seems his only criteria are that the immediately following nominal is given accusative case by transitives and nominative case by intransitives (he makes some reference to an agreement phrase dominating CP, but it doesn't seem to have any relevant surface effects).  So determining this type of "transitivity" doesn't seem that difficult.  Of course, this all assumes you're onboard with C being the primary source of case assignment. ;)

Comment: @lettuce Thank you. I had understood that the following nominal (technically, the closest nominal c-commanded by the complementizer) being given accusative case was a mere *consequence* of the complementizer being transitive, instead of being what *defines* a transitive complementizer. But after your last comment, I decided to review the matter more carefully and it seems that I have overcomplicated things a bit. It's just that simple. Could you turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Will do, once I get a break.

Comment: @tdhsmith, are you still planning on putting together an answer?  Once you do so, Otavio can accept it and we can knock this question off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @Aaron, I've decided to answer my own question. One less unanswered on the list. Yay! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was based on the assumption that the transitivity of a complementizer was some inherent feature of it. One of the consequences of that feature would be that the closest nominal c-commanded by that complementizer would be given accusative case. So, if there was such kind of complementizers in English, it would be something like:

> *I asked if her would go to the party.

But, as it turns out, that assumption is wrong. What defines a transitive complementizer is precisely the fact that it assigns accusative case to nominals, and not the other way around.